# How visual studio ide registers a plug-in

Tags: .net, visual-studio, plugins

I wonder how the VS2008 IDE registers a plugin. A db file, xml etc. since I know that once I call devenv.exe with the parameter to my plugin dll, the next time I launch VS IDE, my plug in is still there. Any leads on where it registers my dll? 
I can also make use of a best practice for such development pattern. I think of developing a big project and registering modules with reflection as if they were plugins. 
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is not a small topic. Among other things you'll want to know what a Visual Studio Add-in actually is. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/vsx for a starting point.

Also, Visual Studio 2010 is using a new technology for plug-ins: the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mef). That's what you should look at.